# How to update one to many relationship in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with updating the following table

[image]

And the data come from the view like below

[image]
this is my code

```
 foreach ($request->input('class_teacher') as $key=>$value){
                $class_teacher =ClassTeacher::where('class_id',$id);
                $class_teacher->class_id = $classes->class_id;
                $class_teacher->teacher_id =$value;
                $class_teacher->save();
            }
```

after the update I want it to be like this one

[image]

Comment: Could you add some code to your question? This makes it easier for everyone to understand your actions and to know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I added some code.

Comment: `ClassTeacher::where('class_id',$id)->get()` Could you try this?

Comment: get error "Method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection::save does not exist."

Comment: Where does the $classes variable come from? This could be the problem?

Comment: Can you ahow how this class is declared ClassTeacher?

Comment: I save some data before it in another table and get the id of that table.

Comment: what do you mean how declared ClassTeacher?

Comment: I mean does it extend the model class, because it needs it for the save method.

Comment: This does not seem like a one to many relation it looks like a pivot table which means it is actually a many to many

Comment: thank you guys from your answer and time, the problem solved

Comment: Please read the documentation on Many-to-Many relationships in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. You do not need a model `ClassTeacher`, you just need `Class` and `Teacher`, with the proper relationship defined (`classes` and `teachers`), then you'd be able to use `attach()`, `detach()` and `sync()` to properly associate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First delete the relationships, then recreate them all again.

```
 ClassTeacher::where('class_id',$id)->whereIn('teacher_id', $request->input('class_teacher'))->delete();
  
  foreach ($request->input('class_teacher') as $key=>$value){
    $class_teacher =new ClassTeacher;
    $class_teacher->class_id = $classes->class_id;
    $class_teacher->teacher_id =$value;
    $class_teacher->save();
```

Comment: thank you so much it solved my problem. I just delete this section ->whereIn('teacher_id', $request->input('class_teacher')), now it work